# Not able to replay JMeter thread. It was working fine some days before. Didnt do any changes on system or script

Tags: jmeter

JMeter script (thread) hangs on pre-login step while replaying the script. It was working fine while script creation.
Able to execute perfectly fine by right clicking on thread and selecting validation option, scripts executes from pre-login to Logout without issues.

If we keep the threads on execution for hours with it only executes for like 3 iterations in 3 hours where response time comes out to be hardly 7-9 secs per steps in thread.

Please let us know what needs to be done cause it hangs and keeps on executing first step.

Answer (score 0):

As per [documentation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) validation mode assumes running test

- with 1 thread
- with 1 iteration
- with 0 startup delay
- without [Timers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers)
- with forcing [Throughput Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller) to execute samplers with 100% probability

Your question doesn't contain enough information in order to help you to troubleshoot the issue, however here are some hints which will be useful in determining the root cause:

- Inspect your Test Plan and look for deviations from the aforementioned behaviour (i.e. long-running timers or large delay configured in Thread Group(s))
- Check *jmeter.log* file - most probably it contains some clues
- Make sure you're following recommendations from [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) guide, in particular:

  - Increase [JVM heap size](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/web.1111/e13814/jvm_tuning.htm#PERFM150) allocated to JMeter
  - Make sure to run your test in [command-line non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui)
  - Make sure to disable all the [listeners](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#listeners) during the test run

If you tried all above and the problem still persists - take a [thread dump](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-take-thread-dumps-7-options) and update your question with your test plan outline, jmeter.log file and the thread dump.